# Behaviour of redirect in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Code for myform.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My form</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="success" method="post">
<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />
<!--
<h5>Password</h5>
<input type="password" name="password" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Confirm Password </h5>
<input type="password" name="passconf" value="" size="50" />-->

<h5>Email Address </h5>
<input type="email" name="email" value="" size="50" />

<div><input type="submit" value="submit" /></div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

controller script 1

```
<?php 
    class Form extends CI_Controller{
        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library('session');
            $this->load->helper('url');
        }
        public function index(){
            $this->load->view('myform');
        }

        public function success(){
            $_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];


            redirect('form/home');
        }

        public function home(){
            $this->load->view('test_home');

        }
    }


?>
```

controller script 2

```
<?php 
    class Form extends CI_Controller{
        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library('session');
            $this->load->helper('url');
        }
        public function index(){
            $this->load->view('myform');
        }

        public function success(){
            $_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];
            echo $_SESSION['username'];
            echo $_SESSION['email'];

            redirect('form/home');
        }

        public function home(){
            $this->load->view('test_home');

        }
    }


?>
```

The question is when I use controller 1, the script work as intended and redirects me to form/home. However, when I use controller 2 I get this error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/parth/application/controllers/Form.php:15)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 564

Backtrace:

File: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/parth/application/controllers/Form.php
Line: 18
Function: redirect

File: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/parth/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

why is the code behaving this way? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`redirect()` uses PHPs 
`header()` function. If you have output before any header you get this error.

This is your Output:

```
echo $_SESSION['username'];
echo $_SESSION['email'];

redirect('form/home');
```

Commented out, or delete it, cause while redirecting you dont need it.

Kind regards

Comment: Glad to have helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Its because, you have `echo`ed two strings in second case.

Comment out this:

```
//echo $_SESSION['username'];
//echo $_SESSION['email'];
```

Redirection is not happening due to this.

In CodeIgniter, redirection uses PHP's `header("Location...")` construct.

This requires that your current script is not outputting anything on screen.

Not even a space (that is why CodeIgniter recommends you should not end up your PHP files with `?>` as spaces can remain there.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh, happy to hear that.